# How to make Hawken work with the Rift?

Tags: hawken, oculus-rift

Last time I read about Oculus Rift support for Hawken, it was in September and considered as [an alpha stage feature](https://community.playhawken.com/topic/26563-hawken-ascension-patch-notes/#entry336703).  Any idea how it did evolve in the meantime ?  I thought that it would be [functional by now](http://youtu.be/EhkiTXVX8Jk)...  So I wanted to find out how to make it work.

First I simply activated the Oculus Rift option in the game's settings, put the game to fullscreen mode and restarded it: no effect.

Then I found [this community thread](https://community.playhawken.com/topic/26996-oculus-rift-help/), added the `-vr` option to the launch shortcut, but no effect.

I kept digging and found this [Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/1m7mrt/hawken_ascension_is_live_native_rift_support/), followed their steps, using the `.ini` files provided: still no change.

Ok, so now, what else can I do ?  I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: In the meantime, I also shot an ticket to their support.  If I get any valuable answer, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Received an answer from their support (full answer at the end of this answer):

> Unfortunately, Oculus support is very limited at the moment. We do recommend that players disconnect one display if using a dual monitor set up. There are also issues with the 720p kits, so you'll need to make sure you have the 1080p kit.

Indeed, I'm using the 720p version.  I suppose that's why.

---

> ```
> from:  Charlie Morrisette <notifications-support@playhawken.com>
> reply-to:  HAWKEN Support <support@playhawken.com>
> date:  Mon, Jan 13, 2014 at 10:25 PM
> subject:   [HAWKEN Support] How to make the Oculus Rift work with Hawken?
> ```
>
> Hey Anto,
>
> Unfortunately, Oculus support is very limited at the moment. We do
>   recommend that players disconnect one display if using a dual monitor
>   set up. There are also issues with the 720p kits, so you'll need to
>   make sure you have the 1080p kit.
>
> As support is limited, we recommend players use the community forums
>   as they are currently the best place for support with the Oculus. We
>   have a dedicated forum within the Medlab for players to seek help:
>
> https://community.playhawken.com/topic/26996-oculus-rift-help/
>
> There is one post that a player that was having trouble, but was able
>   to get it to work. This may included steps that were used in the
>   Reddit thread, but some have notied other changes as well:
>
> https://community.playhawken.com/topic/27045-getting-double-vision-with-oculus-how-to-adjust-ipd-for-hawken/#entry345030
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience,
>
> Charlie

Answer (score 1):

The Rift works with Hawken

Step 1. Set up monitor in control panel with separate screens

Step 2. Right click properties in Hawken on Steam and unclick steam overlay in game DO NOT add -vr to launch options remove it if you have !

Step 3. Run Hawken and click enable oculus in devices via settings

Step 4. whilst in Hawken change game graphics settings to 1280 by 800

Step 5. Restart game

Step 6. Login without looking or touching the mouse at startup after credits clips
GAME ON!!

p.s.
For Point of View drift press F7 to realign vision F11 hotkey to switch to monitor screen

Comment: I've discovered that this doesn't work if your primary monitor is recognized by your system as 'Monitor 3'.  Even if you have only the Rift and another monitor active, if that other monitor is 'Monitor 3' VR won't turn on.

Answer (score 0):

Hawken is one of the few games that recognise the Rift. Do not clone your screens. Just extend the desktop as instructed. The Rift does not need to be the primary screen.

Comment: The issue in my case was simply that I've been using a 720p dev kit (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Worked here its prety cool, with oculus rift dk1. Followed those instructions :

"The Rift works with Hawken

Step 1. Set up monitor in control panel with separate screens

Step 2. Right click properties in Hawken on Steam and unclick steam overlay in game DO NOT add -vr to launch options remove it if you have !

Step 3. Run Hawken and click enable oculus in devices via settings

Step 4. whilst in Hawken change game graphics settings to 1280 by 800

Step 5. Restart game

Step 6. Login without looking or touching the mouse at startup after credits clips GAME ON!!

p.s. For Point of View drift press F7 to realign vision F11 hotkey to switch to monitor screen"

and this

"Hawken is one of the few games that recognise the Rift. Do not clone your screens. Just extend the desktop as instructed. The Rift does not need to be the primary screen."

Thank you very much , see u in the game , powerplant13